# build method doesn't wait for async

Tags: flutter

I am new in flutter and i have some issue with async and await.
I want to , first get some data from server and next build my widget,but my build method doesn't wait for getData and one of my widget in build cant run without any data.
i want a function that wait until the data came from server and next the build method run.

```
Map<String,dynamic> data = Map<String,dynamic>();
 Future getData() async{
    String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/facts/get.php";
    http.Response responseData = await http.get(url);
  setState(() {
     data = json.decode(responseData.body); 
  });
}
@override
void initState()  {
  super.initState();
  getData();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using `FutureBuilder` rather than putting `async` function inside `initState`. For that, you need to alter your `getData` method.

**Example**

Your state has a Future variable called dbFuture

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> dbFuture;
```

your `getData` method should be like this:

```dart
 Future<Map<String,dynamic>> getData() async{
    String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/facts/get.php";
    http.Response responseData = await http.get(url);
    return json.decode(responseData.body); 
}
```

let's make the network request in the initState and without awaiting the result, just asssign it to our Future variable: dbFuture

```
initState(){
  dbFuture = getData();
  super.initState();
}
```

and in the `build` method:

```dart
FutureBuilder(
      future: dbFuture,
      builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
        if(snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done){
          return Container(); // your widget while loading
        }

        if(!snapshot.hasData){
          return Container(); //your widget when error happens
        }

        final data = snapshot.data; //your Map<String,dynamic>
        return yourScreen(); //place your widget here
      },
    );
```

you can refer to the [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) widget in the docs for more info.

Note: Instead of using a method as a Future, we're using Future variable and make our async call in the initState(), this way we make the request a bit early and prevent unnecessary network calls.

Comment: I think calling the getData in initState and without awaiting the result, just assigning it to a Future variable and then using that variable in FutureBuilder is better. It will prevent unwanted network calls

Comment: @mirkancal `FutureBuilder` only calls the `Future` **once**. I think it is way cleaner than calling `setState` inside `initState` as you can use it in a `StatelessWidget`, thus going completely stateless. Also, calling `setState` inside `initState` can cause issues if it is called before the first `Widget` build.

Comment: I didn't call setState in my code though, I don't need it. Also, if your futurebuilder is inside the build method, it can be rebuild, which will cause that the unintended requests firing from every build method call. Since futurebuilder will call the function in its future property. But if you give a future, rather than a method, it will just use the future, doesn't need to call the function.